# Visualize relationship between one factor and multiple others in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have dataframe

```
DF1 <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No")),
                 V2 = factor(c("Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No")),
                 V3 = factor(c("No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No")),
                 Location = factor(c("London", "Paris", "Dallas", "Dallas", "Dallas")))
```

If I want to visualize the relationship between `Location` and one of the other variables, I can draw a simple plot like so:

```
library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(DF1, aes(Location)) + 
      geom_bar(aes(fill = V1), position = "dodge")
```

But what if I want to show in one plot what the responses to all the other variables (`V1/2/3`) are per `Location`? Is there a way to do this in `ggplot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert to long format using `tidyr::gather` and then add a facet...

```
library(tidyr)

DF1 %>% gather(key=key,value=value,-Location) %>% 
ggplot(aes(Location,fill=value)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") + 
  facet_wrap(~key)
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. Thank you, Andrew. But is there a way to show these relationships in a single plot (that is, without `facet_wrap`)? I'm thinking for example assigning different colors to locations and displaying the `V1:3` variables side-by-side.

Comment: @KaC You could just swap `Location` and `key` - i.e. have `key` in the `aes()` and facet by `Location`. You are already assigning colours by `Yes/No`, so I'm not sure how you would also do it by location???